# Understanding syntax in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net-3.5, findcontrol

I am hoping someone can help me understand what is going on in the code line below:

```
Table t = (Table)Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("tbl");
```

I understand `Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("tbl");`
Why is there a (Table) before the Page.FindControl?

Comment: Once you've found your control you need somewhere to put it, right?

Comment: @Dan, thats the "t" in that syntax, not the "Table"

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`FindControl` is declared to return `Control` (at a guess :) whereas you need to store the result in a variable of type `Table`.

The `(Table)` bit is a *cast* - it's basically saying, "I think this will be a `Table`. Check it for me at execution time, and then let me use it accordingly."

Comment: you might also see safe casting by writing it as ...

Table t = Page.FindControl("Panel1").FindControl("tbl") as Table;

All this does is attempt the cast and if the cast is unsuccessful, say its no longer a table but a textbox now, it'll make t null and won't throw an exception.

Comment: @jeriley: Yes, although I rarely find this is useful. Normally when I write a cast, it's because if it's any other type, that indicates a bug - so I want an exception to be thrown.

Comment: I almost never use direct casts in C#. I find `var t = ctl as Table; if (t == null) return fail();` to be much cleaner than `Table t = null; try { t = (Table)ctl; } catch { return fail(); }`.

Comment: @Mark: Why would you catch the exception in the first plcae? Let it propagate up - it indicates a programming error. How are you going to recover from something which shows that things aren't as you expect?

Comment: In my opinion, any cast in C# is an exception waiting to happen. To me it indicates something which is sub-optimal in the design and should probably be factored out at some point. The only time I use casts is when I know that a cast will be significantly more efficient than the alternative and I can satisfy myself that it will never raise an exception.

Answer (score 1):

`Page.FindControl` returns a `Control` type & so you will need to cast it to the relevant type of control you need to use...

Ref.: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/31hxzsdw.aspx

HTH.

**Side note:**

I wish we could do:

```
var t = Page.FindControl<Panel>("Panel1").FindControl<Table>("tbl");
```

Maybe with a bit of extension method magic, we could get:

```
public static class Extension{

  public static T FindControl<T>(this Control control, string id) 
   where T : Control{
       return control.FindControl(id) as T;
  }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

See [() Operator (C# Reference)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0z4503sa.aspx)
And [Casting and Type Conversions (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173105.aspx)

Comment: Thanks ie. This helps me get deeper into the "when" and "why";

Answer (score 0):

FindControl returns a type of `Control`.

Table in your code inherits `Control`. By explicitly casting the object to it's defined Type, you get access to all properties of that Type, instead of only the inherited properties from `Control`.